# Making a Galaga game, can't get the shooting right

Tags: java

I'm currently a student, and this project is just my hobby.

So my game is supposed to be a game similar to Galaga. I can't get the shooting down. I'm using a "KeyDown" statement, but that means you need to hold space down in order to shoot, and I want to be able to just tap space and for it to go forward until the end of the map or it hits an enemy. Any help is appreciated.

Here's my shooting and movement code:

```
// Controls

if (keyDown("left")) {
    player.x = player.x -10;
}

if (keyDown("right")) {
    player.x = player.x +10;
}

if (keyDown("space")) {
    laser.y = laser.y -10;
}

if ((laser.y) <= 0) {
   laser.x = player.x +10;
   laser.y = player.y -20;
}

if (keyDown("space")) {
   laser.visible = true;
} else {
   laser.visible = false;
   laser.x = player.x +10;
   laser.y = player.y -20;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site.  If you can [edit] your question to fit the requirements of this site, please do so.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is some kind of "Game Loop". You should read about it in an article like this: [Game Loops](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/game-loops/24220/view.html)

Finally: If you implemented some kind of "Game Loop" in your Java Game, you can then calculate the actual "Laser" movement (x/y) inside of it. You should also do all the collision handling in this loop.

I hope this helps getting you started with developing games! Cheers.